# Is the pregenerated dragonborn sorcerer's Charisma saving throw bonus wrong?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, character-sheets, pregenerated-characters

When looking at the Dragonborn Sorcerer's [pre-generated character sheet](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/CharacterSheets1-10.zip), the character's Charisma saving throws seem to be wrong. For the level 1, 2, 3 and 4 sheets, I think it should be +5 instead of +6. For the level 10 sheet, I think it should be +8 instead of +9.

My reasoning:

At levels 1, 2, 3 and 4, the CHA modifier is +3 and the proficiency modifier (which applies) is +2. This results in a +5 total, not +6.

At level 10, the CHA modifier is +4 and the proficiency modifier (which applies) is +4. This results in a +8 total, not +9.

**Am I missing something here, or are these actually typos?**

I'm a pretty novice DM, so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: "Are there any other typos in the pregen character sheets" is an overly broad question, and one that doesn't really fit the Stack Exchange format. If you come across another error but are unsure if it's actually wrong, feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Dragonborn Sorcerer has a Charisma of +3 and a base Proficiency of +2, meaning that a +5 Charisma Save is accurate for levels 1-4. At level 5, the Proficiency bump means that +6 is accurate.

By Level 10, the Sorcerer has increased Charisma to 18 for +4 and has a +4 Proficiency Bonus. +8 Charisma Save would be correct.

Definitely looks like typos.