# Why does this WotC pregenerated human paladin have an Int modifier of +1 if their Int score is 11?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, ability-scores, wizards-of-the-coast, pregenerated-characters

On [this page](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/character_sheets), WotC provides a bunch of pregenerated characters.

I noticed that the [level 1 human paladin](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/HumanPaladin_1.pdf) (from the [.zip file linked here](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/HumanPaladin1-10.zip)) has an intelligence score of 11, but a modifier of +1.

How is that possible? (I expected it to be 0.)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help]. Does the rest of the sheet - that is, their saving throws and skills - match an Int modifier of +1 or +0? Since they're not proficient in Int saves, their Int saving throw modifier should match their Int mod. Also, do the sheets for the other levels (2-9) for that character have the same error?

Comment: Answering part of my own question: I managed to find [this PDF](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/HumanPaladin_1.pdf), which seems to match the scores you provided and have the same issue. (It's also [here on DMsGuild](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/171036/Pregen-Characters-Human-Paladin-5e) for free.) It indicates a +3 History and Religion mod, and lists a +2 proficiency bonus. ...And answering my other question, the higher-level sheets do carry over the error.

Comment: Related: [Is the pregenerated dragonborn sorcerer's Charisma saving throw bonus wrong?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134296/is-the-pregenerated-dragonborn-sorcerers-charisma-saving-throw-bonus-wrong)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Human error that simply hasn't been fixed.

The only reason why a 10 or an 11 would be a +1 modifier is because at some point someone made a mistake and it just hasn't been fixed. Either because no one wanted to change it from the original that way everyone is using the same one, or because its just a small thing that's been getting overlooked.

**Even magic items don't increase a mod itself they increase the score.**
Not going to list a bunch but Tome of Clear thoughts.

*Alternatively*
We all know that now that Paladin isn't alignment-locked; they're just trying to give hidden reasons to play them.

Comment: ...Your "alternative" doesn't really make any sense or have any explanation. Non-pregen paladins don't get this "benefit"; it only appears in this set of pregens. Your original guess is likely correct; it was just an error that was overlooked.

Comment: Ya just figured I would have a little conspiracy theory thrown in. WOTC does a good job with all the little things they take care of. So if something like this gets missed it happens to all of us however kinda funny got this far.

Comment: I doubt anyone's really reviewed the character sheets since they were first released/shared. Unlike the Starter Set pregen characters, I think the other pregen characters on the site get much less use and thus problems with them get reported much less often. It's probably worth tweeting Jeremy Crawford or other WotC D&D staff to report the problem.

Comment: Ya that makes sense ^.^